# Magsafe port coating worn away

Tags: macbook-pro, charging, power, magsafe, charger

The plastic coating of my (mid 2010, 13 inch) Macbook Pro's Magsafe charging port has almost completely worn away over time, exposing some kind of shiny metal surface beneath.

How important is this coating?

Is this a fire hazard or a risk to my laptop?

[image: magsafe port] [image]

Comment: The inside of that ethernet port looks kind of nasty - looks corroded! Anyway ... You might be able to clean the MagSafe port carefully with an Exacto blade, then coat the bottom of the port carefully with nail polish to seal it up. be careful not to get the nail polish on the gold conductor pins! YMMV

Comment: Did your MacBook automatically turn on (without pushing power button) when plugged in after that coating broke? I experience this issue.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The coating is just cosmetic and surface protection for the magnets (and they do rust since made of iron).

The insulation (plastic) around the pins is important and it still looks ok to me.

There is no fire or short danger, but you might want to re-coat the magnets surface to prevent corrosion, since you are obviously in some high air pollution (corrosion) area.